# Why datatable is loading data slower in LIVE server?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, server, datatables

I'm trying to load data from a table which contains 3k records. Data loads very fast in local server but when i deployed my code to server (live website) it takes 20-30 seconds to load the whole data.

Mysql Version in server: `5.7.24`

PHP version: `5.6.39-0+deb8u1`

nginx/1.6.2

Ajax:

```
ajaxUrl: '<?php echo $this->MyHelper->Route('admin-get-blog-articles-faq')?>',
        columns: [
            my.common.admin.tableEditColumn('id'),
            { data: 'question' },
            { data: 'created_at' }
        ],
```

Table HTML:

```
<table id="records-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th class="hasinput">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="Question">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="hasinput">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="Date Created">
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th class="all">Question</th>
                                        <th class="all">Date Created</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody></tbody>
                            </table>
```

Controller function code:

```
public function getBlogArticlesFaqAction() {

        //Get all Blog Articles FAQ from DB
        $blogArticlesFaq = BlogArticleFaqModel::getAllForDataTable(array('id', 'question', 'created_at'));

        // Return data array
        return array('data' => $blogArticlesFaq);
    }
```

I'm using mysql and my table structure is below

```
id (PK auto increment), question, answer, created_at, updated_at
```

Show Create Table Local:

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_article_faq` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `question` text NOT NULL,
 `answer` text NOT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3735 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Live Show Create:

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_article_faq` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `question` text NOT NULL,
 `answer` text NOT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3735 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**UPDATE**:

In network tab I noticed that size value increases very slowly so it might be the rendering which takes time! But for DataTables 3k isn't a big value to render, it can easily render that but in my case this size value increases very slowly! And in local it increases very fast.

[Network Tab Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcLeV.png)

Comment: "Data loads very fast in local server but when i deployed my code to server (live website) it takes 20-30 seconds to load the whole data." Slow shared webhosting server maybe?? i advice to contact your live hosting provider.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have other tables which has more data than this table and that loads faster!

Comment: "it takes 20-30 seconds to load the whole data." and is it server load of client load (noticed the javascript, jquery and datatable tag) times? what did you measure?

Comment: It's the rendering which takes much time in server.

Comment: How many rows?  How is the "load" performed?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames Show Create Table is added in EDIT. Rows are also mentioned total records are 3k!

Comment: What kind of web site is this?  Loading 3K rows seems excessive.

Comment: @RickJames it's a web app. I'm fetching 3k records but i'm paginating it via DataTables i.e 10 per page. And it loads very fast locally but in live server it takes time.

Comment: How far away is the "live" server?  Is the client reading one row at a time, or reading all at once?